# Why setter and deleter still work when use only read in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use read only in Python but I setter and deleter still work.
This code

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    def getname(self):
        return self._name
    name = property(fget=getname, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None)

c = Character('c')

c._name #Output 'c'

c.name #Output 'c'

c.name = 'd'

del c.name
```

`_name` is private attribute, why I still use `c._name`

In `property` for `getter` but `setter` and `deleter` still work.

[image]